# Impala SQL query group by with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, impala

Given the following situation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aircraft` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `height` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `table1` (`time`, `aircraft`, `height`) VALUES
(1, 'klm', 605),
(2, 'klm', 603),
(3, 'klm', 705),
(6, 'klm', 505),
(1, 'klm2', 601),
(2, 'klm2', 605),
(3, 'klm2', 605),
(4, 'klm2', 705),
(5, 'klm2', 601),
(6, 'klm2', 301);
```

How to return exactly 1 row for each aircraft where the height is the smallest and time is below 6? The smallest time should be used when the previous conditions return multiple rows for an aircraft.

Expected results:

```
2, 'klm', 603
1, 'klm2', 601
```

It is a very big Apache Impala database, so performance is a consideration for this solution.

Created a fiddle for testing (note fiddle is mysql not impala): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cyKJ1GrfDZXAbhTpQZi7FP/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of MySQL you selected does not support window functions but MySQL v8.0 does support them:

```
select *
from
(
    select 
        time,
        aircraft,
        height,
        rank() over(partition by aircraft order by height, time asc) as rh
    from table1
    where time < 6
) inner_query
where rh = 1
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/edSAUqYqLszQkxPXu3oWd4/2)

(Impala supports them too but the syntax may be slightly different)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return exactly one row per aircraft, then `row_number()` comes to mind:

```
select t1.*  -- or whatever column you want
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by aircraft order by height) as seqnum
      from t1
      where time < 6
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

You specifically want `row_number()` instead of `rank()`, because `rank()` can return duplicates if there are ties.